# Error: unexpected '[' in r

Tags: r

I have an error

```
> for (i in 1:(cutoff_size-1)){work$group[i]=rep(c(0,1),c([i]-1,cutoff_size-[i]-1))}
Error: unexpected '[' in:"for (i in 1:(cutoff_size-1)){work$group[i]=rep(c(0,1),c(["
```

'cutoff_size' is numeric.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `[i]` isn't anything, just use `i`. `[` is used to index vectors/`data.frames`/lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i in 1:(cutoff_size-1)){work$group[i]=rep(c(0,1),c(i-1,cutoff_size-i-1))}
```

this is probably what you're looking for.

[] are used to refer to position in array/data table/list.
If you're using it in a mathematical operation, you do not need the [] around the i.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
However your advice doesn't work.
I want to make group[1], group[2], ..., group[i] like triangular matrix.

Comment: for (i in 1:(cutoff_size-1)){
  if (work$obs<i){
    work$group[i]<-0
  }
  else {
    work$group[i]<-1
  }
}

This is what I thought another way but it doesn't work too.